# Prudent guard elements in a web.config

Tags: asp.net, azure, configuration

**BACKGROUND INFO:**

I have a public web site hosted on Azure (Shared Hosting). Yesterday, without any change on my part, the site starting throwing the following error message:

> An exception occurred while processing your request. Additionally,
>   another exception occurred while executing the custom error page…

After a painful troubleshooting section, I realized the problem was the following section of my web.config.

```
    <system.data>
       <DbProviderFactories>
           <add name="MySQL Data Provider" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" ..... />
       </DbProviderFactories>
    </system.data>
```

Azure must have relocated my instance to another host that already had this MySQL Data provider defined in the machine.config, and the duplicate config entry ended up taking down my entire site.

I could have used a *clear*  or *Remove* tag to bypass the error, but as it turns out, I no longer needed  MySQL functionality, so I just removed the entry entirely and that fixed the problem.

**HERE'S MY QUESTION:**
Using a 3rd party service, I have no control over the machine.config settings. Yesterday demonstrated that I can't assume they will always be what they are now. I've seen it's common practice to use a *Remove* tag in the connection strings section to guard against a situation where your desired connection string was already defined somewhere else in the hierarchy. So there is another example where it pays to be explicit with an added *remove* tag.

What I'm looking for is a somewhat comprehensive list of tags in the web.config, that should be guarded with either a *remove* or *clear* tag to protect against unforeseen duplicate tags from configuration sources out of our control.

Comment: We have previously found it useful to clear membership providers, roleManager providers, appSettings, httpModules, remove named staticContent extensions, staticTypes mimeTypes, dynamicTypes mimeTypes, connectionStrings. This may be overly comprehensive, but we have also had issues with settings inherited from customer machine configuration as such have been cautious. Not comprehensive or technically justified list, so comment rather than answer.